# In RVCT Compile Environment, how to wrap a function

Tags: c, arm

I got some problem with RVCT compile environment, need your help.

There is a function like this

```
int lib_func(int b)
```

but i don't have the source code of this function.

I want to wrap this function and add some debug flag.

In GCC, i can create `__wrap_lib_func`, and call `__real_lib_func`,

then modify the makefile like this -Wl wrap, lib_func

But in rvct 3.1, i cannot use -wrap to request linker help to wrap this function.

Could you teach me how to wrap function in RVCT complie environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the $Super$$/$Sub$$ functionality in the linker, that lets you "intercept" calls:
http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0474i/Chdefdce.html

Of course that document is for version 5.03, but the functionality was there in 3.1 and I would be surprised if the syntax has changed.